# How to append a version number of a current app to core dump?

Tags: c++, linux, coredump

Is it possible to add a software version number of the cored file, let's say we have 100 software versions, each with a specified number that is `#defined` in the app.

When the core dump happens, how can I append this number to the core file, so that it can be mapped to the correct image?

Mapping a core file with every release I have would take some effort!

Comment: I don't understand what you call a release number. But I provided an answer which probably is relevant.

Comment: It does not have any sense. What is dumping core is some process executing some ELF files, and ELF executable files don't have version or release numbers in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux (specifically), according to [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)  and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man pages, you could change `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

Software don't have (necessarily) a release number. It is at most a convention that some software are following (but not others).

Perhaps you might use symlinks on your binaries. Alternatively, you could, very early in your `main`, copy some version string into a well identified buffer - perhaps a variable `char my_current_version[32]` (and examine that buffer in the code dump).